# zend studio 11 how insert a date + name comment with shortcut

Tags: php, zend-framework, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

I have to add and modify many PHP page of a project.
I'd like a keybord shortcut(ctrl+key) to insert something like this:
//Sergio October 25, 2014 
or something else I want as comment, to keep track of my changes. 
Does anyone know how to create a custom shortcut?
Thaks!
Sergio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I remember, Zend Studio doesn't allow to create shortcuts for templates, but you still can define a template and when you start entering the first few letters of that template, the studio will suggest to 'autocomplete' the entire template.

To do it:

1. Open Window -> Preferences -> PHP -> Editor -> Templates
2. Click New...
3. Type some name of the template (you'll type first letters of this name later), say "authorname"
4. In the Pattern field type

   `// ${user} ${date}`
5. Save the template.

Now every time when you start typing "aut" it will suggest you your new pattern, just hit Enter and it will turn into //Sergio October 25, 2014.

I hope it helps.